# Como adicionar biblioteca do postgres no eclipse/android

Tags: android, eclipse, postgresql, android-eclipse

Estou fazendo um app em android, que vou conectar direto com um banco postgres em um servidor. Porem não sei adicionar o jar do postgres, se eu adiciono no Java Build Path nas propriedades do projeto ele da erro e não executa mais. Então como eu adiciono a jar, e qual jar devo adicionar, jdbc 3, 4 ou 41.
Muito obrigado desde já.

Fiz o que me disseram ai de colocar na pasta lib e adicionar no Java Build Path. E deu esse erro abaixo.

```
10-14 16:51:53.720: E/CONEXAO(9610): NAO CONECTADO No suitable driver
10-14 16:51:53.722: D/AndroidRuntime(9610): Shutting down VM
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610): Process: br.com.android.sicsm, PID: 9610
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.android.sicsm/br.com.android.sicsm.view.CategoriaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.PreparedStatement java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.PreparedStatement java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at br.com.android.sicsm.dao.CategoriaDAO.listarCategoria(CategoriaDAO.java:52)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at br.com.android.sicsm.view.CategoriaActivity.carregarLista(CategoriaActivity.java:50)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at br.com.android.sicsm.view.CategoriaActivity.onCreate(CategoriaActivity.java:28)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5720)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
10-14 16:51:53.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9610):     ... 10 more
10-14 16:51:59.463: I/art(9610): Heap transition to ProcessStateJankImperceptible took 50.478906ms saved at least 283KB
```

Abaixo segue o codigo da conexão.

```
private final String endereco = "jdbc:postgres://10.1.32.31:5432/sics";
private final String usuario = "postgres";
private final String senha = "postdba";

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(endereco, usuario, senha);
```

Novo erro:

```
10-14 17:13:29.244: E/CONEXAO(15297): NAO CONECTADO A tentativa de conexão falhou.
10-14 17:13:29.244: D/AndroidRuntime(15297): Shutting down VM
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297): Process: br.com.android.sicsm, PID: 15297
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.android.sicsm/br.com.android.sicsm.view.CategoriaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.PreparedStatement java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.PreparedStatement java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at br.com.android.sicsm.dao.CategoriaDAO.listarCategoria(CategoriaDAO.java:52)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at br.com.android.sicsm.view.CategoriaActivity.carregarLista(CategoriaActivity.java:50)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at br.com.android.sicsm.view.CategoriaActivity.onCreate(CategoriaActivity.java:28)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5720)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
10-14 17:13:29.246: E/AndroidRuntime(15297):    ... 10 more
10-14 17:13:30.875: I/Process(15297): Sending signal. PID: 15297 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Acredito que você deve criar uma pasta chamada `libs` na raiz do seu projeto. Coloque o `jar` dentro dessa pasta e adicione-os ao `Build Path` (pode ser que não precise).Acredito que isso vá funcionar.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, porem ele ta erro. No suitable driver. Fala que o driver não é adequado :/

Comment: Você precisa ver qual a versão correta (a mais recente talvez) e fazer o carregamento do Driver (usando o `Class.forName`) antes de abrir a conexão.

Comment: Olha o que eu adicionei ai a cima, é o erro e abaixo o codigo

Comment: Sua conexão esta nula, verifique se a url de conexão não é: `jdbc:postgresql://10.1.32.31:5432/sics`

Comment: Resolveu a questão do driver, mas agora ele não consegue conectar, da outro erro, vou adicionar o erro na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você esta falando de PosgreSQL ? 
Sobre Android, não tem espaço o suficiente então, não usamos MySQL o PosG, mas sqLite. No caso de você, precisa comunicar com um servidor tipo Web (com Posgrsql o MySQL). E muito perigoso tentar comunicar diretamente, porque você vai dever colocar a senha, id etc... no app Android. E, em muitos casos, o servidor não vai aceitar: na maioridade dos casos, somente um codigo colocado no mesmo servidor que a base de dados pode acessar (segurança!)

O que você precisa fazer e colocar uma pagina tipo PHP no servidor e, com o app Android, chamar esta pagina. Esta pagina PHP vai ler os dados da BDD e quando ela vai fazer "echo" dos resultado, a sua app Android vai receber os dados.

Em Android, para fazer isso, precisa fazer um extend de Asyntask() e usar HttpPost(). Quando você vai enviar por exemplo http://dominio.com/call_bdd.php?nome=marcello o PHP vai fazer um GET para receber a informação:

```
   $nome = $_GET['nome'];
```

Depois o PHP vai ler a BDD e quando ele vai fazer "echo" do resultado, o Android vai receber na sua parte doInBackground() da class AsyncTask.